# Clearing GridView without causing EmptyDataText to show

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with an assigned "EmptyDataText" value.

Its holding search results so I do want it to display the EmptyDataText when there aren't any search results.

However when I clear the search results (by setting DataSource to null and causing a databind), I don't want the EmptyDataText text to show. Any way of doing this without changing the visibility?

Comment: Why aren't you changing your EmptyDataText?

Comment: I could do that, but then I need to put it back in every time I databind with search results - which is just as tedious (and prone to errors) as changing the visibility

Comment: "Put it back everytime" not so bad. Just set your EmptyDataText before your search function and clear grid function.